# process XML response and convert to collection which is not in proper format

Tags: c#, xml

I have to process XML response from a 3rd party REST API over which I do not have control. problem is the XML response in not in proper format something like this:

```
<XML>
<Meta>
<Status>Success</Status>
<Debug/>
</Meta>
<Result>
<abc>
 <DivisionID>tttttttttt</DivisionID>
 <UserName><![CDATA[ xxx#xxxxx]]></UserName>
 <UserFirstName>xxxx</UserFirstName>
 <UserLastName>xxxx</UserLastName>
 <UserAccountType>xxxxxxx</UserAccountType>
 <UserEmail>xxxxx@xxxxx.xom</UserEmail>
 <UserAccountStatus>Active</UserAccountStatus>
</abc>
<def>
 <DivisionID/>
 <UserName><![CDATA[ xxx#xxxx]]></UserName>
 <UserFirstName>yyyy</UserFirstName>
 <UserLastName>vvvvvv</UserLastName>
 <UserAccountType>uuuuuuuuu</UserAccountType>
 <UserEmail>oooo@vvvvvv</UserEmail>
 <UserAccountStatus>Active</UserAccountStatus>
</def>
....contd
</Result>



       var requestUri = new Uri(uriString);
       HttpWebRequest httprequest =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    var httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();
    Person people = new Person();
    List<Person> lstPerson = (from _person in         xmlDoc.Document.Element("Result").Elements("Result")
      select new Person
      {
      userName = Xdocument.Load(httpresponse.GetResponseStream()).Root.ToString(),
      userEmail = _person.Element("UserEmail").Value
      }).ToList();
```

I need to retrieve the node with value "abc" and "def" and store them in UserName which itself is root node, and also to retrieve the values in between them. so how to do this I tried various ways but was unable to to so.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.  1) What is your class `Person`?  2) How do you get from `httpresponse` to `xmlDoc`?  3) `XDocument.Parse()` throws an exception for your XML because the ending tag is missing.  Can you make sure you have a usable error-free sample of the XML you want to parse? 4) What are `abc` and `def`?

Comment: You want `userName` to be `value1`?  But there is also an element named `UserName`.  Do you want to ignore that value completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

To create a list of your `Person` classes using element names for `userName` and the value of the `UserEmail` sub-element for `userEmail`, you can do the following:

```
        try
        {
            // Load the XML from the external site
            XDocument xmlDoc;

            var requestUri = new Uri(uriString);
            HttpWebRequest httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            using (var httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = httpresponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            }

            // Extract the name & email.
            var people = xmlDoc
                // Get the "Result" node
                .Root.Elements(xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace + "Result")
                // Loop through its elements
                .SelectMany(result => result.Elements())
                // Deserialize the element name and UserEmail sub-element value as a Person
                .Select(element => new Person { userName = element.Name.LocalName, userEmail = element.Element(xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace + "UserEmail").ValueSafe() })
                .ToList();

            // Process or return the list of people
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any web exception encountered.
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            // Or rethrow if it can't be handled here
            throw;
        }
```

Using the [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ValueSafe(this XElement element)
    {
        return element == null ? null : element.Value;
    }
}
```

**Original Answer**

Your question is unclear.  But if you are asking

> If I have loaded an `XDocument` from some XML, is there a way using `XmlSerializer` to deserialize a portion which is an embedded list when each element of the list has a custom element name?

Then you can do this as follows:

1. Loading the `XDocument`
2. Navigate to the list you want to deserialize.
3. For each element, remember the element name, then *overwrite* it with the class name.
4. Use [`XElement.CreateReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.createreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create an `XmlReader` for just that element, then pass it to an `XmlSerializer` for deserialization.

I.e.:

```
    // Load the document
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var people = doc
        // Navigate to the list
        .Root.Elements("Result")
        .SelectMany(r => r.Elements())
        // Deserialize each element in the list as a KeyValuePair<string, Person>
        .Select(element =>
            {
                var name = element.Name;
                element.Name = typeof(Person).DefaultXmlElementName(); // Overwrite name with name used by serializer.
                using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
                {
                    var person = (Person)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person)).Deserialize(reader);
                    return new KeyValuePair<string, Person>(name.LocalName, person);
                }
            })
        .ToList();
```

Given the XML string

```
    string xml = @"<XML>
        <Meta>
            <Status>Success</Status>
            <Debug/>
        </Meta>
        <Result>
            <abc>
                 <DivisionID>tttttttttt</DivisionID>
                 <UserName><![CDATA[ xxx#xxxxx]]></UserName>
                 <UserFirstName>xxxx</UserFirstName>
                 <UserLastName>xxxx</UserLastName>
                 <UserAccountType>xxxxxxx</UserAccountType>
                 <UserEmail>xxxxx@xxxxx.xom</UserEmail>
                 <UserAccountStatus>Active</UserAccountStatus>
            </abc>
            <def>
                 <DivisionID/>
                 <UserName><![CDATA[ xxx#xxxx]]></UserName>
                 <UserFirstName>yyyy</UserFirstName>
                 <UserLastName>vvvvvv</UserLastName>
                 <UserAccountType>uuuuuuuuu</UserAccountType>
                 <UserEmail>oooo@vvvvvv</UserEmail>
                 <UserAccountStatus>Active</UserAccountStatus>
            </def>
        </Result>
    </XML>
    ";
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string DefaultXmlElementName(this Type type)
    {
        var xmlType = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlTypeAttribute>();
        if (xmlType != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlType.TypeName))
            return xmlType.TypeName;
        var xmlRoot = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();
        if (xmlRoot != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlRoot.ElementName))
            return xmlRoot.ElementName;
        return type.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dbc for the answer.